# regulate PHP anonymous function to 5.2

Tags: php, anonymous-function

need help on regulating anonymous function. cant get through this one..

```
$marks = implode(',', array_map(function() {
                            return '?';
                        }, explode(',', $props)));
```

How can i convert this to be compatible with php 5.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php 5.2 don't support lambada:

```
function callback($value)
{
    return '?';
}

$marks = implode(',', array_map('callback', explode(',', $props)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `create_function()`:

```
$marks = implode(',', array_map(create_function('', '
                            return "?";
                        '), explode(',', $props)));
```